# navigator.sendBeacon not working in internet explore browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have write form unload event inside proxy code is not working in internet explore browser.

Example:

$(window).unload(function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebAPI/api/Values/Get?id=1',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true, //blocks window close
            success: function () {
                alert('sucess');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });

Comment: bellow code is working crome browser but not working ie browser $(window).unload(function () {
        
        if ('sendBeacon' in navigator) {
            navigator.sendBeacon("WebAPI/api/Values/Get?id=1", null);
        } 
    });

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer is an obsolete browser. It doesn't have a lot of modern web features, including the [beacon API](https://www.w3.org/TR/beacon/) ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=beacon)). You could feature-detect the beacon API and fall back to `XMLHttpRequest`.